# Sintaxe do for sem o contador

Tags: c++

sou iniciante em programação e estou estudando a linguagem C++, consequentemente também é a minha primeira vez utilizando esse site. Mas enfim após fazer um curso básico sobre a linguagem referida, baixei um código fonte para ir entendendo um pouco da pratica.

Então lendo uma parte do codigo me deparei com essa linha de codigo:

```
for (Creature* spectator : list) { }
```

Mas quando estive vendo esse tipo de laço havia alguns argumentos mas que era definido como o exemplo a seguir >> For (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) <<

A pergunta é: O que essa linha quer fazer? Que estrutura de laço é esse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o `for` do C++ pode ser usado da maneira tradicional com um contador, especificando o início da contagem, o fim e os passos (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) ou usado como um equivalente mais legível para um loop que opera em uma variedade de valores, como todos os elementos em um container, como no caso que você cita. Neste caso, ele está contando todos os elementos de uma lista. Você pode ver como utilizar dessa forma neste link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for. Desta última maneira, ele é usado parecido com o `for_each` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each). Já que você está aprendendo, sugiro começar com códigos mais simples. Espero ter ajudado.